# Makefile + nmake + set target platform to v140, from the command line

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nmake, cl

Visual Studio 2017. I've got a makefile generated by a script. Required toolsets are installed. How do I instruct nmake to compile for the v140 toolset instead of the latest one?